# Tikz| How to change line color and style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, draw

I want to know how to change the color and the style of line in my graph, it's possible for marks but not for lines. this is my code :

```
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=.1714cm, x=.5cm,font=\sffamily]
    %axis
    \draw (1,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (9,0);
    \draw (1,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (1,35);
  %ticks
  \draw (1.5,1pt) -- (1.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {20$\times$10};
    \draw (2.5,1pt) -- (2.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {20$\times$20};
    \draw (3.5,1pt) -- (3.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {40$\times$20};
    \draw (4.5,1pt) -- (4.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {40$\times$40};
    \draw (5.5,1pt) -- (5.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {60$\times$30};
    \draw (6.5,1pt) -- (6.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {60$\times$60};
    \draw (7.5,1pt) -- (7.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {80$\times$40};
    \draw (8.5,1pt) -- (8.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north, rotate = 45, above=-.7cm] {80$\times$80};
  \foreach \y in {2,6,10,14,18,22,26,30,34}
        \draw (0.9,\y) -- (1.1,\y) node[anchor=east] {\y}; 
    %labels      
    \node[below=1.5cm] at (x axis mid) {Instances};
    \node[rotate=90, left=1cm] at (y axis mid) {CPU time [in hundreds of seconds]};
    %plots
    \draw plot[mark=*, mark options={fill=white}] file {f_3_2.data};
    \draw plot[mark=triangle*, mark options={fill=black} ] file {q_3_2.data};
    %legend
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2,24)}] 
    \draw (0,0) -- 
        plot[dashed, mark=*, mark options={fill=white}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) 
        node[right]{Algo. LOQ};
    \draw[yshift=\baselineskip] (0,0) -- 
        plot[mark=triangle*, mark options={fill=black}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0)
        node[right]{Algo. \cite{Ref9}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i get this :

[image: my graph]

when i try to change the lines color or style by the following code, it doesn't work and without catching errors :

```
\draw plot[style=dashed, draw=red, mark=*, mark options={fill=white}] file {f_3_2.data};
```

even the position of the coordinates label can't be changed !

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try `\draw[<color>] ....`. For your image is simpler to use `pgfplots` instead pure `tikz`.

Comment: Try this ```\draw[..., ultra thick, densely dashed, red] plot ...```.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your welcome and your quick response. I try to work with pgfplots, but i did not find a clear documentation to do what i need (like the picture). With pure tikz, it's well unless the styles and colors. If you have a good documentation or a quick code, it will be a great help. Thanks

Comment: @fromthebeeland I try it, but it doesn't work !

Comment: This link can be helpful, it's relevant to your question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105570/how-to-plot-functions-like-x-fy-using-tikz

Comment: @fromthebeeland thank you for the help, it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use `pgfplots` package. It has extensive package manual, which is part of package installation or you can find in CTAN by googling for *Manual for Package pgfplots*.

An uncomplete example (since your data table is not known), can be:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xtick = {0,1,...,9},
    xticklabels = { ,
                    $20\times10$, $20\times20$, $40\times20$, $40\times20$,
                    $60\times30$, $60\times60$, $80\times40$, $40\times80$},
    x tick label style = {rotate=45, anchor=east},
    xmin=0, xmax=9.5, xlabel = {instances},
    ymin=0, ymax=35,  ylabel={CPU time [in hundreds of seconds]},
    legend pos={north west},
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
             ]%axis
\addplot coordinates { (1,2)  (2,6)  (3,10)
                       (4,14) (5,18) (6,22)
                       (7,26) (8,30) (9,34)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An example, how to use table of diagram's data, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473874/global-definition-of-nodes/473942#473942).